# Set date of jQuery UI Datepicker in "MM yy" format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I'm trying to use jQuery UI datepicker in my project and it seems that I can't set date at render time in format as `"MM yy"`. But I still can change it in `onClose` method after page is loaded. If I change initial date format to `"yy-mm-dd"` initial date is set correctly.
Example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/1446/

In this example if you change `dateFormat` to `"yy-mm-dd"` then the date is set correctly to a value of `realDate` variable. If `dateFormat` is set to `"MM yy"`, the date is set to current date.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: so what is your problem, you don't to set current date?

Comment: here is a jquery asset might help u..http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Comment: I suppose that if  `.datepicker('setDate', realDate)` fails, then date is set to current date by default.

Comment: This demo is very good, but it can't help, because I need dateFormat to contain only month and year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting date at the end instead of in beginning,here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/1446/

```
    $(function() {
    var queryDate = '2009-11-01',
    dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g)
    realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);  
                                    // months are 0-based!

    $('#startDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "MM yy"
    }) // format to show

    .datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true)
    .datepicker("option", "changeYear", true)
    .datepicker("option", "showButtonPanel", true)
    .datepicker("option", "onClose", function(e){
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
         var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
         $(this).datepicker("setDate",new Date(year,month,1));
      }).datepicker('setDate',realDate);
    });
```