# Datepicker change format to number

Tags: jquery, .net

How can I change jQuery datepicker format MM/yy to number?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/yy",
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-60:+0",
                altField: "#datepicker",
                closeText: 'OK',
                prevText: 'Précédent',
                nextText: 'Suivant',
                currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
                monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
                dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
                weekHeader: 'Sem.',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: '',
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));

                }
            });

            $('.datepicker').focus(function () {
                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
                    my: "center top",
                    at: "center bottom",
                    of: $(this)
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set date of jQuery UI Datepicker in "MM yy" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828717/set-date-of-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-mm-yy-format)

Comment: what do you mean by "format MM/yy to number"? Do you want a month to be printed as a number instead of full name?

Comment: yeah I mean instead of having August/2019 for exemple to have 08/2019

Comment: The `mm/yy` format already displays the month as a number. See [possible formats](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate). When do you have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you mean to a real date-value, try this:

```
var d = new Date(2018, 11, 24);
```

or

```
var d = new Date(2018, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  appendText: "(mm/y)"
});

or 
 dateFormat: "mm/y"